# What exactly is a 祝版, and how is it used in ceremonies?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, culture

In the chengyu story behind 入木三分 (rù mù sān fēn), the emperor has a 祝版 created for a ceremony in which he makes sacrifices to his ancestors. I did some initial searches and found that a 祝版 is wooden board that has text upon it, but strangely couldn't find much else. Is this board supposed to be a certain size, and is it supposed to have a certain amount of words/kind of text? How is this plank used during the ceremony?

Thank you!

Chengyu story sources:

[Baidu](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%85%A5%E6%9C%A8%E4%B8%89%E5%88%86/830568)
[National Academy for Educational Research](https://dict.idioms.moe.edu.tw/idiomView.jsp?ID=-58&webMd=2&la=0)
[Hanyu Da Cidian](http://www.hydcd.com/cy/gushi/0486rm.htm)
[Qi gushi](https://www.qigushi.com/chengyugushi/1661876441134452.html)

Answer (score 1):

祝版, also 祝板, is a piece of rectangular/square wood or paper board that carries praying/congratulatory messages (祝文) for a sacred ceremony. The size was not fixed, but regulated and produced by the department of skilled works (工部) in accordance with the status of the object of each ceremonial event.

https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E7%A5%9D%E7%89%88/13348092